# Can I have one Javascript function for multiple JQuery accordions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have multiple (completely separate) JQuery uses of accordion in my webpage, and have one Javascript function for each occurrence. Am I over complicating this could I simplify the Javascript to have one function that they all use

```
<script>
    $(function () {
    $("#accordion0").accordion({
        active: false, 
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content"
    });
});</script>
<script>
    $(function () {
    $("#accordion1").accordion({
        active: false, 
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content"
    });
});</script>
<script>
    $(function () {
    $("#accordion2").accordion({
        active: false, 
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content"
    });
});</script>  
.................
```

Comment: do you have   a jsfiddle link?

Comment: You can either group all selectors like `$("#accordion0, #accordion1, #accordion2").accordion` or have a common class for all accordions, such as `.accord` and do  `$(".accord").accordion`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a class in common with all your html accordion; example:

```
$ (function () {
   $(".class-my-accordion").accordion({
        active: false, 
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content"
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems better because It doesnt change as i get more accordions, but how do i chnage my html do i just go from <div id="accordion1" > to <div class="class-my-accordion"> ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor, I think you just did

Comment: Just add the class to your div html like this:   <div id="accordion1" class="class-my-accordion" >,  <div id="accordion2" class="class-my-accordion" >,  <div id="accordion3" class="class-my-accordion" >... ETC... As much as you need it. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can group all your selectors into one function, yes:

```
$("#accordion0, #accordion1, #accordion2").accordion({
    active: false, 
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: "content"
});
```

Comment: Lol. Indeed. It uses CSS selector syntax. So, if you are at all familiar with how css selects elements then you can figure this syntax out. This can also be helpful: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp